# Method Referencing is not working in collect method for stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stream

I'm trying to sort the elements in the list and collect and print it in separate list using java 8 streams below is the code.

Working Code:

System.out.println(                coursesList.stream().sorted(comparingByNoOfStudents).collect(Collectors.toList()));

But when it try the same with method referencing it's giving error:

System.out.println(
coursesList.stream().sorted(comparingByNoOfStudents).collect(Collectors::toList));

Below is the message :

java: no suitable method found for collect(Collectors::toList)
method java.util.stream.Stream.collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super com.java.functional.basic.Courses>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) R
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super com.java.functional.basic.Courses,A,R>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A
(argument mismatch; java.util.stream.Collector is not a functional interface
multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface java.util.stream.Collector))

Comment: Why did you expect it to work with a method reference when it already works without a method reference?

Comment: You can use a [Method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as an argument of a method which expects a **Functional interface**. One-argument version of `collect()` expects an instance of type [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) which is **not** a *functional interface*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. You need to pass a collector to `collect`. Not 'a method that can make a collector', you pass *a collector*.

a method reference is way to say: Don't call the method - instead, I want the concept of the method call as a thing I can hand off so that other folks can actually call it.

Take the `.sorted` method which can sort it for you if you provide a function that tells you which of any 2 elements is 'the earlier' one. You do not want to run this 'which one is earlier, a or b?' method, you want to hand it off.

That's what lambdas (`->` syntax) and method references (which is just shorthand for `x -> invokeThatMethod(x)`) are for. the `collect` method doesn't ever want one.